# How to handle repeated records in SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have a simple data set like below:

[Employee Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZKxm.png)

I need minimum start date & max end date of an employee whenever there is a dept id change or status code change.

So i wrote this formula for Min start date-
**select emp id, dept id, status code , min(start date) from tablename group by emp id, dept id, status code.**

I've got the below result :
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJnEv.png)

The highlighted dates are missing in my result because dept id and status code got repeated. Since i am taking min start date, its not considering those records.

Likewise, i need to get max end date also.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Update - Adding sample data and expected ouptut.

create table employee(

emp_id int, start_date date, end_date date, dept_id int, status_code varchar(100));

insert into employee values

('2233','1/1/2020','1/25/2020','123','Active'),

('2233','1/25/2020','2/15/2020','123','Active'),

('2233','2/15/2020','3/29/2020','123','Active'),

('2233','3/29/2020','4/11/2020','456','Active'),

('2233','4/11/2020','5/5/2020','456','Leave'),

('2233','5/5/2020','6/17/2020','456','Active'),

('2233','6/17/2020','7/22/2020','456','Active'),

('2233','7/22/2020','8/19/2020','789','Active'),

('2233','8/19/2020','9/30/2020','789','Terminated'),

('2244','1/10/2020','1/25/2020','122','Active'),

('2244','1/25/2020','2/19/2020','122','Leave'),

('2244','2/19/2020','3/31/2020','122','Active'),

('2244','3/31/2020','4/11/2020','322','Active'),

('2244','4/11/2020','5/5/2020','322','Active'),

('2244','5/5/2020','6/17/2020','322','Active'),

('2244','6/17/2020','7/22/2020','322','Active'),

('2244','7/22/2020','8/24/2020','422','Active'),

('2244','8/24/2020','9/24/2020','422','Terminated')

Expected Output:
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReQuU.png)

Comment: Have you tried select emp_id,min(start_date)as min_start from your_table group by emp_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get maximum end date too you can modify the code as below:

```
select emp id, dept id, status code , min(start date) max(end date) from tablename 
group by emp id, dept id, status code
```

And if I got you correctly you want to employee wise department wise status wise minimum start date and maximum start date. But if any of the condition repeats itself not consecutively but after another condition this condition will be considered separately to calculate minimum start date and maximum end date.

Please share the sample data list in csv or excel so that I can replicate that to test. And you are using **Teradata** database.

**You can achieve what you what through below query:**

```
select employeeid,deptid,status,min(strtdate) MinimumStartdate,max(enddate) MaximumStartdate from 
(
select *,(row_number()over(order by EMPLOYEEID,STRTDATE) -ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by employeeid,deptid,status order by employeeid))grp
from emp) t
group by employeeid,deptid,status,grp
```

I have tested that in sql server. Result is shared below. (Pleaes change variable names according to your table)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is island and gaps problem and you can achieve the desured result using `analytical function` and `group by` as follows:

```
select emp_id, dept_id, status_code , 
       min(start_date),
       Max(end_date)
From (select t.*,
             Row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by start_date) as rn,
             Row_number() over (partition by emp_id, dept_id, status_code order by start_date) as rn_chng
  from tablename t) t
group by emp_id, dept_id, status_code, rn- rn_chng
```